# Taking polynomial inverses over a field?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $f \in F_p[x] / q(x)$. I know for a fact that the inverse of $f$, $g$ exists in the field. Taking the regular inverse is easy, but I'm looking for the compositional inverse.

I'm looking for algorithms to find the inverse of $f$.

When can we find a $g(x) \in F_p[x]/q(x)$ so that $f(g(x)) =x$?

Additionally, if you know of any papers that talk about the existence of inverses that would also be useful.

Comment: Do you mean that you are looking for an algorithm to find the inverse of $f$, rather than  of $g$? Also, to be clear, to you mean you want to find an inverse with respect to composition, rather than with respect to the field operation (which is multiplication)?

Comment: What is the source of your knowledge that $f$ is bijective? If this is just given to you as a black box promise, I don't see how you can do better than Lagrange interpolation. But there are only a few known classes of easily recognized permutation polynomials (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_polynomial ), so if your polynomial belongs to one of them, you might be able to do better.

Comment: EG If your polynomial is $x^3$ for $p^{\deg q} \equiv 2 \bmod 3$, then the inverse polynomial is $x^{(2 p^{\deg q} -1)/3}$.

Comment: It looks like there is a fair bit of literature in this area; the relevant search terms are "permutation polynomial" and "compositional inverse".

Comment: Question simulposted to m.se, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4750141/existence-and-algorithms-for-finding-the-composition-inverse-of-a-polynomial-ove in violation of rules on both sites.